# How can I upload photo to facebook album from android app using following graph API?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am new to android development. I am trying to post photo from an android app to user's facebook album. I added following code after I logged in the user with permissions "user_friends"

```
new GraphRequest(
    MainFragment.mAccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "/me/photos",
    params,
    HttpMethod.POST,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }

    // This is my code for user login at app start

    post = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mLoginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();
    mLoginManager.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, mCallback);
    mLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("user_friends")); //user_friends // publish_actions
```

Please guide me

Comment: why user_friends? what for? you only need publish_actions.

Comment: also, you forgot to mention the most important information: what is the problem exactly?

Comment: I am sorry. I missed a lot of information. But, I was able to find the issue and write working code. I forgot executeAsync()

Answer (score 0):

I did a mistake .. Firstly, my question was incomplete .. I have found the issue .. Following seems to be working.

```
        MainFragment.mLoginManager.logInWithPublishPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
        Bundle params = new Bundle();

        params.putString("url", "http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg");
```

/* make the API call */
            new GraphRequest(
                    MainFragment.mAccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                    "/me/photos",
                    params,
                    HttpMethod.POST,
                    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */
                            Log.d("MainFragment:", "onCompleted mAccessToken = " + MainFragment.mAccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken());
                        }
                    }
            ).executeAsync();